# JBoss-provided libraries in Maven-managed Java EE app

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss5.x

It's actually pretty unlikely for me, but it seems that there is no direct answer over the net about importing JBoss-provided dependencies into Maven-managed Java EE application to be deployed within it.

AFAIK there are 2 things somehow related to the problem, that is `jboss-as-client` artifact for external (in sense of JVM) JBoss clients and `jboss-as-component-matrix` artifact with huge `<dependencyManagement>` block defining version of the libraries that JBoss uses. The latter artifact is pretty useful since I can use Maven's import scope to have all version properly set up. The one that is missing (AFAIK) i something like `jboss-as-client` but for deployed Java EE application. Something, that I can depend on with `provided` scope and have all stuff in the classpath, including platform-related APIs (like EJB or JMS) and AS-specific stuff (like EJB-ext or `jboss-messaging`) and possibly some other stuff from `lib`, `lib/endorsed` and (mainly) `common/lib` directories. I know that probably a better practice (and religion-compatible) would be to be explicit with dependencies used in modules but the way I'm asking about is much more pragmatic for me (sorry), at least for Java EE applications that really use many standard APIs.

I'm really curious about your way of dealing with such challange. I'm using 5.1.0.GA version of the AS.

Comment: May be i miss something, but what exactly is your question? Are you searching for an artifact for the server side which contains only a dependencyManagement part or what?

Comment: I'm searching for a way of providing the libraries contained within JBoss AS that are accesible for deployed Java EE application managed by Maven. The artifact with dependencyManagement definitions I've already found ('jboss-as-component-matrix'). What I haven't found is something like POM-type artifact with dependencies that are actually provided by the JBoss AS (e.g. 'common/lib').

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing, and I'm on AS 7.  There doesn't even seem to be a jboss-as-component-matrix for 7, all I've found so far is this chart: https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide your own (infrastructure) maven project which just packages all the mentioned dependencies and all your JBoss projects depend on this infrastructure project with scope `provided`.

But shouldn't you compile just against the specification jars instead of the concrete implementation?
Like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Jump to the first occurrence of "Java EE 6 API" on http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/.

Comment: as I mentioned, I use JBoss 5 which is Java EE 5 implementation. AFAIK, there is no similar artifact for Java EE 5 which works (there is one but causing some troubles). But even if it would be, I prefer to have many artifacts with isolated APIs, because application and libs that dependend on them, have it provided thanks to parent's `<dependencyManagement>` (that's my current solution). But because of JBoss 5 classloading issues (as @Joop Eggen mentioned in another answer), it is far more safe to provide all JBoss libs to the applications. Some of them are useful, anyway.

Comment: This answer is valid... but use JavaEE 5.0 API as dependency for compilation against API. In case your implementation depends on lib included in JBoss, I recommend to match exactly the version provided by JBoss (log4j, CXF...) - but I do it on a per-jar basis. In that case it does not matter if the jar is also in EAR/WAR or not...

Comment: I accept this answer since it's valid and works. @Yves comments in this topic are also very valuable and thanks for that. It seems that my current solution is more or less something like you guys suggest here.

Comment: If we use provided scope: 1- where should we add jar files in JBOSS ? 2-what configuration should change in JBOSS ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't like this answer, but as the libraries are provided at run-time by JBoss, other than using a `provided` scope, it is not really your affair. The classes of any unstated transitive dependency will be loaded by a different class loader (presumably), and live nicely together with the application classes.

For the not so nice coupled classes, what @MichalKalinowski said is true.

Comment: I do not agree. Since JBoss 5.x version, the ClassLoading mechanism is really non-standard and it is likely to occur big troubles. For instance, if you have Spring jars in your application... it prevents JBoss JAX-WS implementation based on CXF to work !

Comment: That disqualifies my answer sufficiently, @YvesMartin, thanks.

Comment: @YvesMartin, that's true. JBoss 5 classloading is really weird (at least default behaviour) and it is a problem itself.

Comment: We will have to live with still for a while. There is no big changes on that point in 6.x or 7.x versions.